# Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I saw the other question dealing with this, but it did not help out.

I have a function that has a dictionary parameter like so:

```
 func addPushNotificationPayload(payload: [NSObject: AnyObject]) { }
```

within this function I'm attempting to get the value of certain keys from "payload" like so:

```
 if let uid = payload["uid"] as? NSString, let recipientID = payload["recipient"] as? Int {
```

However, I'm met with the error "Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'"

How do I go about resolving this issue?

Comment: just use the object for key instead of `[subcript]` for example  `payload.object(forKey: "uid")`

Comment: Value of type [NSObject: AnyObject] as no member 'object'

Comment: I think since you are passing push notification body which is on a json form, you should change the type of the payload as `NSDictionary`

Comment: You should review [these search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Ambiguous+reference+to+member+subscript).

Comment: Consider that in Swift 3 the type of the payload has been changed to the generic JSON type `[String : Any]` (for example in the delegate method `didReceiveRemoteNotification`).

Comment: payload: `[NSObject: AnyObject]` should be `[String:AnyObject]` I guess.

Comment: I'll try changing it to that and let you know how it goes